# Button action inside wordpress preview customizer area

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've been working on the customizer area in my own wordpress theme and my goal is to be able to click on a button inside the preview area to upload an image instead of using the panels in the customizer section area.

I'm starting out small and for now I just want to see if I can even activate a button inside the preview area.

I haven't been able to and for a long time I thought it had something to do with the preview area taking some time to load. But after taking that into consideration I still can't not get any action out of the button. I do see "preview is loaded" but nothing happens when I click the button.

This is my script:

```
   (function ($) {
 // Wait for the Customizer preview to be ready
 wp.customize.bind('ready', function () {
 wp.customize.previewer.bind('ready', function (message) {
  alert("Preview is loaded");
  // Handle click event for the "Add New Gallery Item" button
  $(document).on('click', '.add-new-gallery-item', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Button was clicked!');
  });
  });
 });
 })(jQuery);
```

I have enqueued the JS at the customize_controls_enqueue_scripts action with customize-controls script as its dependency.

and of course I have checked a million times that the button has the class of "add-new-gallery-item".

Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks